# Node Red Error: Cannot create property '_msgid' on string

Tags: mysql, sql, mqtt, node-red, mosquitto

I have this set up in Node Red:
[image]

Using this SQL (Function) code:

```
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO temperature(temp, date) VALUES('" + 
msg.payload + "', 'NOW()')";

return msg.topic;
```

And getting this error:

```
function : (error)
"TypeError: Cannot create property '_msgid' on string 'INSERT INTO 
temperature(temp, date) VALUES('1.23', 'NOW()')'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: run it in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is just returning a string (msg.topic), it needs to return a whole object.

```
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO temperature(temp, date) VALUES('" + msg.payload + "', 'NOW()')";

return msg;
```

Comment: Aha :) I've just started trying Node Red a couple of hours ago, so I am not fully into the way it works, but this solved it! Thank you!